# AngularJS HTTP Post response.data is Raw Text of PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, http-post

I am fairly new to angular and php. I am trying to make a post from an html page to a php page using angularjs. The post succeeds but response.data is the plain text of the php file instead of the json object I echo.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="LoadPage('kengoss@yahoo.com')">

<p>Welcome Dr. {{last_name}}</p>

</div>
<script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http)
    {

      $scope.last_name = 'Summers';
      $scope.LoadPage = function($email)
      {
        $scope.last_name = $email;
        $http({
          method: "post",
          url: "test.php",
          data: { email: $email},
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function mySuccess(response){
            $scope.last_name = response.data;
          },function myFailure(response){
            $scope.last_name = 'Failure';
          }
        );

      }

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$array['last_name'] = 'Goss';

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Is your webserver configured right?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
.then(function mySuccess(response){
  let dataObj = JSON.parse(response.data);

  $scope.last_name = dataObj.last_name;
  ...
```

Comment: I get a JSON.parse error because of an unexpected character at line 1 column 1. Probably because it is trying to parse the actual text of the php file and not the output.

Comment: @IanSummers Please post a screenshot of your console, logging `console.log(response.data);`